# PHP: 'rotate' an array? with array_unshift

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to rotate an array (5x6 for example) on pos to right each value, the last must to be the first

```
//ADD VALUES (RANDOM)

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<7;$j++){
        $aleatorio=mt_rand(10,99);
        $a[$i][$j]=$aleatorio;
    }
}

echo "<br>"; / SHOW IN A TABLE

echo "<table border=1 width=200px >";

for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){

    echo "<tr>";

    for($j=0;$j<count($a[0]);$j++){
        echo "<td>".$a[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

echo "<br>";echo "<br>";

$last=array_pop($a); //KEEP THE LAST VALUE

array_unshift($a,$last); //PUT IN THE FIRST POSITION

//SHOW AGAIN

echo "<br>";echo "<br>";

echo "<table border=1 width=200px >";

for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){

    echo "<tr>";

    for($j=0;$j<count($a[0]);$j++){
        echo "<td>".$a[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Why does the last value appear in first row last column? not in [0][0] position

Comment: The code seems to do what I would expect - it is shifting the last row (not the last value but the entire row) from the end to the start.

Comment: i want only the last value not the whole row

Comment: If you want the last value of the last row, you could do: `$last = array_pop(array_pop($matrix));`

Comment: Try and reduce the size of your matrix (for brevity), and provide input and output examples.  I suggest you removing the random values, replacing with a counter.